# Creating tabbed image gallery - changes my flexbox cards

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I am using the W3C tabbed image gallery for a page on a website. It works fine, except it reformats other pages where I have used a flexbox card gallery. The images in the cards get distorted and the cards themselves get thinner.

Another problem I would like help on is centering the enlarged image and reducing the size of the images.

```js
< script >
  function myFunction(imgs) {
    var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
    var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
    expandImg.src = imgs.src;
    imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
    expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
  } <
  /script>
```

```css
/*styling for gallery page images*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/*Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

.container-gallerypage {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}


/* Expanding image text */

#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/20.jpg" alt="The Eli Lechtzer Family, circa 1915. (L - R, seated) Chana Butzarsky Lechtzer, Raizel (Rose) Lechtzer, Eli Lechtzer, and Golda Lechtzer (standing). 
    " style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/2.jpg" alt="Sisters of Stavisht" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/6.jpg" alt="Four girls" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/22.jpg" alt="Raizel Lechtzer,  circa 1917. Raizel, wearing her school uniform, is about 7 years old in this photo." style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-gallerypage">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:80%">
  <div id="imgtext" style="text-align: center;width:75%;"></div>
</div>
```

I've posted the html for the gallery page and all my css at CodePen. https://codepen.io/Ovimel/pen/YgzVeg

The W3C page I am trying to replicate is here - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp

Note: I'm a once every few years beginner coder, and as you can see from the css, I am picking up code around the web to create this page, so I don't really understand where and how items affect each other. It would help if you keep your explanation pretty simple. And, I'm not sure I even posted what you would need to help me. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example code, they have used images with the same width and height, so there won't be any design breaks. But in your case, you have used images with dimensions that make those design breaks.

Can you try this code and check whether this solves your issue.

```
.column {
float: left;
width: 25%;
padding: 10px;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.column img {
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
max-width: 100%;
}
.container-gallerypage {
position: relative;
display: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh - this helped center my images and give them a standard size in the gallery and width on the enlargement. The image text, however, was not centered. I played around and changed the width from 75% to  width:100% on the html div id="imgtext" The problem now is that the longer text on the first image overflows both the left & right sides. I tried overflow: hidden and overlow-x: hidden to the CSS for the img text and in the html div id, but no luck. Still have to look at why flexbox cards are distorted, as well. I think it's the border-box code.

Comment: Ok, YES! I changed the * universal selector used for border box in the image gallery columns to the column selector and that kept the gallery photos clean as suggested above and fixed the images on the pages that used flexbox to layout. What a relief! Now, just need to figure out why the lengthy text isn't centering on the image of the gallery page.